# How to deal with DM that railroads you, and then says you skipped things?

Tags: problem-gm, railroading

Mid-campaign we approached a building, and then the DM railroaded us into a certain side room, says that we barged in, and the guards in the room shouted to a different room for backup. The DM then said

> ...there are two other doors that no one checked and that could hold other henchmen...

I feel like we were forced into this position as we had no chance to look into , and is likely to carry on doing similar things unless someone speaks up.

**Is there anything I can do/say to try to avoid this type of gameplay with this GM in future?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This question could be improved with a few details; what system are you playing? and how exactly did he 'railroad you into the room'?

Comment: "then the DM railroaded us into a certain side room" — could you please elaborate on how this happened?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I've voted to close this as unclear until you can give us a few more details about the situation. Remember we weren't at the table and only know as much information as you give us. Things that will matter to answerers include: game systems and editions, age and experience of players and dm, are you playing a module or a homebrew adventure, and most importantly a more detailed description of the situation. The more we know, the better we can help you.

Comment: @linksassin this can happen in any game system and edition, so I think this is system-agnostic. Age and experience is a nice additional information, but I don't think it is an appropriate reason to close this question as unclear.

Comment: @Vylix The main reason it is unclear is the lack of detail about what the DM did to make it "railroading" that is why I VTC. I then gave a list of information they could add to help make it clearer. I didn't VTC for lack of a system because you are correct this is system-agnostic.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer beyond the obvious "don't play with a GM who ignores player making choices" with this question, or are you posting a rant to complain about your GM? (An understandable reaction to the situation, but not something that fits our format very well)

Comment: @Vylix That’s what we have the system-agnostic tag for. Also we had a big kerfluffle a while ago about an otherwise system-agnostic answer being invalidated by the system in question directly addressing it.